# Weirdness while booting, and now ubuntu wont recognize my 4090

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I just built a new computer. Everything was working wonderfully until I moved it upstairs to my desk.

I couldn't get it to boot until I plugged the HDMI cable into my motherboard, it booted, and then I powered it off and connected it to my gpu. Worked fine then. I follow this procedure every time I need to restart my pc. It usually works fine.

I just rebooted my pc, and went through that whole task again, but now it won't recognize my gpu. I have a RTX 4090 btw. Nothing changed, no new installs or anything. Really need some help here fellas, thanks!

Comment: Try a temporary disk with Windows to see if the issue is software or hardware.

Comment: Maybe its not seated properly after the move. Open the box and make sure.

Comment: It works fine on windows (thank god), but I need it to work fine on Linux. I'm getting an mt7921e hardware init failed upon booting into ubuntu

Comment: sudo apt-get --fix-missing update to get missing updates.

and

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  to install new dependencies
Maybe try to repair Ubuntu

Comment: I will try this, thank you!

Comment: The sudo apt-get dist-upgrade did something, it works!!

Comment: You guys are amazing, I really appreciate all the help here, and literally 30 minutes from problem origin to completely functional system!

Comment: I'm going to wait an hour or so to make sure everything is still fine, but yes, I will, assuming there are no issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works fine on windows (thank god), but I need it to work fine on
> Linux. I'm getting an mt7921e hardware init failed upon booting into
> ubuntu

Try to repair Ubuntu:

sudo apt-get --fix-missing update ...  to get missing updates.

Then

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ...  to install new dependencies

Repairing Ubuntu should probably help here